# "Easy-to-make-typos" alternative?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a good, compact word or phrase that would explain one's ability to make typos?
I mean, I'm trying to write something like this:

> Now you can use this feature without either non-predictable XML, or ***easy-to-make-typos*** "magic strings"

It regards a fluent API project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would reword that,

> Now you can use this feature without unpredictable XML or **typo-prone** "magic strings."

(*Neither . . . nor* is redundant with *without*.)

Comment: But you could use "without either ... or ... " or "with neither ... nor ... ".

Comment: Or "error-prone"

Answer (score 4):

How about a simple *easily mistyped*?

> Now you can use this feature without unpredictable XML or easily mistyped "magic strings".

As Callithumpian and Colin Fine [suggest](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21739/easy-to-make-typos-alternative/21747#21747), "without neither... nor..." should be re-worded, and *unpredictable* is the word you are looking for. I will add that I'm not quite sure what "unpredictable XML" is supposed to mean to begin with, but I guess it will be clear in context.

Comment: I accepted the first answer. Really, I'm not native, so I cannot judge, if "easily mistyped" is better than "typo-prone" or not. Anyway, your answer helped me to understand more deeply my neither-nor mistake, so +1 also. Thanks!